# What are the major differences between IE7 and IE8 that a web developer should know?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

I've just downloaded IE8, which replaced my IE7, but that's okay because IE8 has a 'compatibility view' which is meant to render pages like IE7 (not sure about the JavaScript).

I was wondering if there is a listing on the internet of all major differences a developer should know between the versions. I've searched Google a bit but haven't found a satisfactory listing.

So, what should I (or any other web developer) know about getting my site working optimally on IE8, and what are the major differences between the two?

Comment: I've only just downloaded it! All I know is about the meta tag to opt in to non IE7 rendering mode (but I'd like to hear someone elaborate on it)

Comment: You just downloaded it, fine. But did you only just now *hear* about it?

Comment: Nope. But it has seemed to popping up more and more on the net (forums/blogs) so I thought I'd have a look at it.

Comment: No, he's heard about it for a while, but every time he asked about the differences someone gave him a lot of unwarrented grief about it, and he hasn't been able to get a response yet.

Comment: There is a Microsoft tool that allows you to view documents in different IE rendering engines - well worth seeking out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would start by looking here:

[Internet Explorer 8 Readiness Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/readiness/developers-new.aspx)

[Differences between IE8 Compatibility View and IE7](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx)

[IE8 Developer Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/ie/default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a comprehensive "gotcha" list of rendering quirks until more folks have it installed.  There are a bunch of new features like Accelerators that you can develop to build new features into IE8.  [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2008/11/22/developing-for-ie8-accelerators-and-web-slices.aspx) looks like a good start.