# What are the major differences between IE7 and IE8 that a web tester should know?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

What are the major differences between IE7 and IE8 that a web tester should know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have had lots of CSS issues during testing, especially positioning items in an absolute position (eg images).

Comment: Even the IE 8 (Compatibility mode) did not render the same as true ie7

Answer (score 2):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664582/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ie7-and-ie8-that-a-web-developer-should-kn) at SO. It takes a look from the developer's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

one major change is that IE8 doesn't center block level items with `text-align: center` the way that IE7 would. Now you **must** use `display: block; margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

IE7 generates new stacking context, even if z-index:auto, for positioned boxes, doesn't support position:inherit, position:absolute = hasLayout in IE7/IE6, position:fixed does in IE7.

are you separating ie styles? if you are, and using conditionals, just check syntax, and exclude IE8 for starters, so  - prolly will resolve itself.